# How do you fix Google OAuth API - (403) There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key

Tags: console, google-api, google-oauth

I have recently moved a project over to another server. The domain name is the same, it has just been pointed to the new server. The URL is exactly the same. Since moving the project over however I get this error when the app tries to connect to googles OAuth api.

```
{
"name": "Error calling GET https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/analytics\/v3\/management\/accounts\/~all\/webproperties\/~all\/profiles?key=AIzaSyBKUP8JriiOnFnbJm_QYt_bHTMuHf-ilAI: (403) There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
"url": "\/analytics\/statistics.json"
}
```

The obvious reason (based on the error message) would be that I haven't added the new server IP into the list of allowed IP's in the devlopers console under APIs & auth->Credentials->Key for server applications.

I have added the IP. I've checked the domain has propagated by pinging it and the new IP comes up which has been entered in the console so i'm struggling to work out why it doesn't work.

Has anybody come across this before that may be able to help me solve it?

Comment: What does google-app-engine have to do with this Q?  GAE and "having moved the project to another server" seem incompatible -- can the extraneous tag be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem for a while as well but finally solved it:

I noticed when trying `wget http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/` from my server it would actually return an IPv6-address, when on the API key's config page I had entered the IPv4-Address of my server. Once I added the IPv6-Address, my requests where finally accepted.

Answer (score 7):

Go to Project -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> API Key -> Create New Key -> Browser Key. It may take upto 5 minutes to reflect changes.
And it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

After you added your new server IP you need to generate a new API key from the Console. This message shows up when access in not properly configured. Look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/errors) and scroll down to "accessNotConfigured".

So, go to your developer console,  Project -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> Public API Access -> Create New Key -> Server Key. Use this new key and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for replying but unfortunately this doesn't fix this issue. The IP the request is coming from is definitely set in the console and I have created a new server key a couple of times now and updated the details in the code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem, Michael?  I have the same issue - IP address correct, tried regenerating the key and starting again from scratch, but the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project -> APIs & Auth -> Credentials -> Public API Access -> Create New Key -> Server Key >> Accept requests from these server IP addresses (Optional) section,
then remove all the IP Address and Update it first, then try it. And, later you can add the specific IP address which did weirdly work for me.