# There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. code :403 in android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

First of all its not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965421/how-do-you-fix-google-oauth-api-403-there-is-a-per-ip-or-per-referer-restric) because that was not about android, and moving project to new server.

I've used this link to retrieve youtube videos id of specific channel

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={MY_KEY}&channelId={MY_CHANNEL_ID}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults={NUMBER_OF_RESULT}";
```

but when I tried to read the result from the given URL I got following error

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"ipRefererBlocked","message":"There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. 
Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"}],

"code":403,"message":"There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions.

 Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."}}
```

I've regenerated my api key by deleting previous, checked my channel id and api key many times but couldn't identify whats going wrong here.

Please help me fix this issue, and what should I have to do to get rid of this ?

Comment: have you tried the solution in that answer? Can you tell us your IP address you are trying it from according to http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/ and show us the per-IP / per-referer configuration

Comment: @Gavriel 202.52.233.248 It's my PC's IP but what to do with this ? The app is used from android device.

Comment: But is it allowed to be used from anywhere? Or at least from that IP?

Comment: @Gavriel It is allowed from my IP. It works if we put video ID manually and play. But when I tried to retrieve the playlist by using the given URL and tried reading json then it shows this result in log output.

Comment: Where(android/pc) does it work, and where it doesn't? What is the ip of your android? Do you go via the same IP on WiFi or on 3G?

Comment: @Gavriel 64.233.173.143 It's my IP of mobile where I was debugging the app. Now what should I have to do ?
Is it the correct approach I've tried above to get the json data, Or will prefer another way of retrieving playlists. Please share if you have another way too. I will be glad.

Comment: why are you making http calls directly and not using the java API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102193/discussion-between-madhab-dhakal-and-gavriel).