# Android api key 403 usage limit error when adding SHA-1 to key

Tags: android, google-api

I have the following code fragment:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events nextEvent =
                       client.events().list(getResources().getString(R.string.google_next_match_calendar_name))
                               .setTimeMin(new DateTime(new java.util.Date(), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()))
                               .setMaxResults(5)//-->get 5 next events
                               .setOrderBy("startTime")
                               .setSingleEvents(true)
                               .setShowDeleted(false)
                               .setKey(getResources().getString(R.string.google_calendar_api_key))
                               .execute();
```

This causes the following exception:

> W/System.err:   "code" : 403, W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
>   W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits", W/System.err:
>   "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured
>   on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. 
>   Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key
>   configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",

The API key that I use is properly setup with the SHA-1 of both debug.keystore and release play store keystore.
api_key in developer console :

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965421/how-do-you-fix-google-oauth-api-403-there-is-a-per-ip-or-per-referer-restric

Comment: You are refering a server key answer. This is an android api key. It does not include IP but SHA-1 fingerprints